# Python how to plot a frequency pie chart with one column using plotly.express

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame and I only want to plot the frequency of one column, for example, the count of cars of different brands. Cars: [FORD, FORD, BMW, GMC, GMC, GMC, GMC.....] I want to plot them in pie charts of any suitable graphs, without using matplotlib.

I tried to create pivot tables, which are like Ford: 4, Chevy: 3, BMW: 5, GMC: 10. but I don't know how to access the column labels and I can't use them in plotly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can groupby `cars` and get the counts in a new column `count` like so

```
df = df.groupby(['cars'])['cars'].count().reset_index(name='count')
```

Then you may use [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/pie-charts/) to render a pie chart like so

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.pie(df, values='count', names='cars', title='Cars')
fig.show()
```

[image: Have some pie!]

Comment: I had to save the new DataFrame into a separate variable, which I then used for my pie chart, but then it worked. Great, thank you!